# Force folder rename while in use

Tags: c#

I have a service running on a webserver that waits for a zip to be dropped in a folder, extracts it, and then moves it to a certain directory.  Since we want to replace the directory in question, it renames the existing folder (very large folder, takes a couple minutes to delete), then moves the extracted files in its place, then deletes the old folder.  The problem is: when it tries to rename the existing folder, it gets 'Access to the path '<>' is denied.', I believe because the folder is in constant use by the webservice.  Is there a way I can force the folder to rename, or take control and wait for it to not be in use?  Or is there another way I can accomplish this goal?

Comment: I don't think so, Not if the folder or any of the files that are inside the folder are in use. You could programitcally pause the service while you rename the folder and then re-start it once its completed?? You need to make sure that it is your service that's locking it down.

Comment: The webservice is what is locking it down.

Comment: Then try pausing/stopping the service maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "force" a rename while any process holds an underlying operating system handle to the folder(it would be horrible if you were able to do that).

You can:

- Implement pause/resume functionality for the webservice so it can be told to pause its work and release the handles, then resume after you are done.
  or
- Stop the webserice completely, do your work, then start the webservice

Comment: Obviously not what I wanted to hear, but it seems to be the only solution.  We ended up scrapping it because of this, and are looking to weekly deployments on the off-cluster to get this data out there.

Comment: @KyleW, are you able to modify the service that is constantly using the folder? do you _have_ to rename/delete the folder it's using _before_ it switches to the newly extracted folder? You could get around it by exposing a public property such as `FolderName`, and set it to the new folder so it will switch to using the new folder, then delete the old one. It's just a suggestion as I don't have the complete information and requirements but you may have given up too quickly, maybe that was a good time to go back to the whiteboard and do a different design.

Comment: A little late on my response, but the data we're extracting is all created by a 3rd-party with VERY limited customizability.  We can't even change the root folder for it in the website without asking them to do it for us.